# WebView not accepting some cookies

Tags: android, cookies, webview, android-webview, session-cookies

I'm loading a website in Webview which uses some cookies to store session. I've written following lines to accept cookies

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
}
webView.loadUrl("https://www.irctc.co.in/nget/train-search");
```

At one stage (after payment from payment gateway), `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method is called and after that it's supposed to land to transaction success page but it keeps going to login page. This is my method:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    Log.d(TAG, "The URL is loaded in webview itself");
    return false;
}
```

Using Chrome Developer Tools, I can see following cookies for website
[image: Cookies used by website]

When I call method `CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url)` I can see that the cookies **JESESSIONID** and **SLB_Cookie** are present in webview, but not sure about that **Local storage** cookie. Also, if I remove the **Local storage** cookie in Chrome, I'm getting the exact same page (login page) instead of transaction success page like WebView. So I think if by any means if I check whether the Local Storage cookie is present in webview or not, and if not present then if I add it, my job would be done. But I'm not able to achieve either of the task.

Comment: Do you want to pass the login object to your cookie on url in webview ?

Comment: I just want that Final page which is opened should be transaction success page, not a login page. The reason for which (I think) is local storage cookie for that website is not loading in webview so I want that to be loaded. Or if some other alternative (or cause) for issue is there, I would like to know it.

Comment: you have to figure it out that hows that site accepting cookie and you have to pass it like i answered it below

Comment: Hi Vishal. Please do not add chatty material here. That you have researched the problem is taken for granted, you do not need to state it. How long you have been stuck is probably not relevant, and is generally only added to posts for the sake of begging and pleading. We prefer thanks and other niceties not to be added - we prefer technical writing here, and often point out that Stack Overflow is not a chatroom.

Comment: For reference, I sometimes add this advice in the comments: _Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Comment: In general, moderators will side with editors who gently and politely enforce this guideline. Here is [the canonical reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass your login users data to a cookie in Webview the do it like this
The other day I had to pass my login object to particular URL 
as follow.

```
            WebSettings settings = webViewRoi.getSettings();
            settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
            settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();


            FormsDTO formsDTO = new FormsDTO();
            FormsDTOProfile dtoProfile = new FormsDTOProfile(LoginActivity.loginInfoDTO.getProfile());
            formsDTO.setProfile(dtoProfile);
            formsDTO.setAuthorized(true);
            formsDTO.setToken(LoginActivity.loginInfoDTO.getToken());

            String out123 = gson.toJson(formsDTO);

            String auth2 = URLEncoder.encode(out123, "UTF-8");

            String z = "userInfo=" + auth2;  // here userinfo is the key of cookie
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);


            cookieManager.setCookie(url, z);
            webViewRoi.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webViewRoi.loadUrl(url);
```

So if you know the key name of cookie then you can pass your login object through cookie. hope it helps you.

Comment: It's my object you can also ignore that and pass your token into a serialized form

Comment: Thanks a lot... CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
            cookieManager.setCookie(url, z); did the job for me... I had tried setCookie method before as well but I think that was missing something. But now it's working like a charm :)