# PHP and WebView - Cookie doesn't are the same

Tags: php, android, cookies, webview, logout

I'm using a WebView to show a web application.
All works, except one thing:

My login:

```
setcookie("USER_ID", $my_id, time() + 86400);
```

My logout:

```
setcookie("USER_ID", 0, time()-3600);
header('Location: ./index.php');
```

after that, i see the login page. And all is normal. The print_r of $_COOKIE array is:

```
Array
(
 [PHPSESSID] => e44ceefl92jvesh0kddmdicmv1
)
```

there isn't any USER_ID. and is all correct.

But **if i close the Android Webview and reopen this app**, magically I am logged in! And if I print the cookie Array, is:

```
Array
(
[USER_ID] => 1  // WTF?!?
[PHPSESSID] => e44ceefl92jvesh0kddmdicmv1
)
```

***it seems like the android webview send to the server an older cookie array.***

Please Help!

--------------------edit----------------

also if i print

```
cookieManager.getCookie("MyUrl");
```

there is the USER_ID cookie that i've deleted with logout

Comment: Why are you storing the user id in a cookie in the first place, why is that not stored inside the session? And are you saying that you get the exact same session id again?

Comment: I don't understand. If i close the app without logging out, it works fine. And is what I want. If i log out and close app, and restart app, magically i'm still logged in. That's the problem

Comment: don't set cookies like this .. check this my answer . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686044/webview-not-accepting-some-cookies/52720962#52720962

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do this onPageFinished

```
CookieManager.getInstance().cookieManager.flush();
```

it seems to work, but i'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Try setting path and domain when you first set cookie and when you remove it, often times in my experience this solved a lot of problems with cookie.

And also instead setting cookie value to 0 on log out just set it to empty string like this ""

If that does not work, then also add `unset($_COOKIE['USER_ID']);` to your log out part, so it will be like this;

```
setcookie("USER_ID", 0, time()-3600);
unset($_COOKIE['USER_ID']);
header('Location: ./index.php');
```

Comment: unset($_COOKIE['USER_ID']); works only server side. it doesn't delete the browser cookie

Answer (score 0):

The cookie can't be set because the name given in the domain argument in the **setcookie function** don't match with your host

in your case it's empty :(

So listen !

(My System Info: macOS using android studio with android virtual device manager API 24 For testing WebView)

My Android WebView url: http://**192.168.1.147**:8080/pfe

My PHP CODE :
`setcookie('CUSTOMER_ID','$id',time() + 24 * 86400 * $user_stay, "/",'localhost');`

And this will not work because **My Android WebView url** don't match with my **Setcookie Domain name**

SO **TRY** TO HAVE COOKIE DOMAIN NAME SAME THAT YOUR COMPUTER IP ADDRESS

---

I HAVE USED **ANDROID WEBVIEW & PHP & MYSQL & FLUTTER**

Answer (score -1):

I did not see your code but i can assume that the user is not properly logged out.

Logout code for php sesssion shold look like

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();

// thats all
// you can unset all php sessions if you wants
?>
```

Comment: Is not a problem of session, because when the user is re-logged in, is because of cookies.

   if($_COOKIE['USER_ID'] > 0) .....

Comment: Why don't you use Session instead of cookies to store user data

Comment: Because session end when the browser is closed

Comment: What you need is not cookies you need Token based authentication. where your php generates a token on users login, this token will be called via json and stored on client side via LocalStorage. You can now send the token with any request and validation will be performed on the php backend side. On loggin out, you will need to clear the localstorage so that any unauthenticated users are not allowed to loggin once logged out. This can easily be implemented on Reactjs, Redux, Angularjs, Angular and Vue.